# i am creating application where submitting from to aweber but i also need input fields to store on db

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter-3, aweber

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl">
```

I am creating an application where submitting from to aweber but I also need input fields to store on db. But I also need that inputs to store inv database at my end how can I get them in PHP as we can't have two actions.

Comment: Generally you have to try doing it before it will happen

Comment: how can you explain a bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript or jquery

when your submit button clicked you can send form data to your url and also you can post that data to your controller then you can insert it to the database.

```
<form id='myform' method='post'>
<input />
<input />
<button id='submit'></button>
</form> 
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
      'dataType': 'json',
      'type': 'POST',
      'data': $('#myform').serialize(),
      'url': 'http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl',
       success: function (data) {
         //what ever you want to do with the return data
       }
   })
  $.ajax({
      'dataType': 'json',
      'type': 'POST',
      'data': $('#myform').serialize(),
      'url': 'your code igniter controller url',
       success: function (data) {
         //what ever you want to do with the return data
       }
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with the help of CURL

```
    public function signup()
{
    $fields_string='';
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl');
    $fields = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'meta_web_form_id' => '1122',
        'meta_split_id' => '',
        'listname' => 'abc',
        'meta_redirect_onlist' => '',
        'meta_adtracking' => 'My_Web_Form',
        'meta_message' => '1',
        'meta_required' => 'name,email',
        'meta_forward_vars' => '0',
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    {
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    rtrim($fields_string,'&');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $returned = curl_exec($ch);
    $this->register_user($fields);
}
```

$this->register_user($fields); // This function will store values in my database as we are passing name and email to that function